# jQuery Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception

I'm getting the error on the title. See the screenshot at http://i49.tinypic.com/s6jc03.png

The error is not always there, sometimes I refresh and get no error.

I already put all the code inside $(document).ready(function(){} just in case was something with the DOM not being ready.

base.js:2453 ->

```
$('#SetList_Close,.fb_close').live('click',function(){
    $.fancybox.close();
    return false;
});
```

Any ideas what's happening? The error happens on Chrome. I haven't tested other browsers.

EDIT: I'm using jquery 1.7.2 from googleapis.com

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the code you wrote? I'm guessing your selector is incorrect/not selecting anything...

Comment: Yes... it's a bit tough to help debug code that we can't see. ;)

Comment: The screenshot shows that you're using a minified jQuery. This doesn't help matters. What version of jQuery are you using? Do you have plugins loaded too?

Comment: The code is very big, too many files. I'm hoping for someone who might have seen this or a similar error.

Comment: @amnotiam version 1.7.2 http://i49.tinypic.com/s6jc03.png

Comment: Well one thing is that you should not use `$.fn.live` that is being deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

What is `$.fancybox` supposed to do? I do not see that as [an api on their page](http://fancybox.net/howto)

Did you mean to use the `$.fn.fancybox` version?

```
$('.some-element').fancybox({
       href: this.href,
       overlayOpacity: 0.2,
       centerOnScroll: true,
       scrolling: false,
       hideOnOverlayClick : false
   });
```

This would make sense as an error since the object you're calling fancybox on is not a DOM element wrapped in jquery.